# Memory usage of zfs for mapped files

Tags: solaris, mmap, zfs

I read the following on https://blogs.oracle.com/roch/entry/does_zfs_really_use_more

> There is one peculiar workload that does lead ZFS to consume more
>   memory: writing (using syscalls) to pages that are also mmaped. ZFS
>   does not use the regular paging system to manage data that passes
>   through reads and writes syscalls. However mmaped I/O which is closely
>   tied to the Virtual Memory subsystem still goes through the regular
>   paging code . So syscall writting to mmaped pages, means we will keep
>   2 copies of the associated data at least until we manage to get the
>   data to disk. We don't expect that type of load to commonly use large
>   amount of ram

What does this mean exactly? does this mean that zfs will "uselessly" double cache any memory region that is backed by a memory mapped file? or does "using syscalls" mean writing using some other method of writing that I am not familiar with. 
If so, am I better off keeping the working directories of files written this way on a ufs partition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) since it is not development-, but operations-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that zfs will "uselessly" double cache any memory region that is backed by a memory mapped file?

Hopefully, no.

> or does "using syscalls" mean writing using some other method of writing that I am not familiar with.

That method is just regular low level `write(fd, buf, nbytes)` system calls and similars and not what memory mapped files are designed to support: accessing file content just with reading / writing memory by using pointers, using the file data as a byte array or whatever.

> If so, am I better off keeping the working directories of files written this way on a ufs partition?

No, unless memory mapped files that are also written to using system calls sum to a significant part of your RAM workload, which is quite unlikely to happen.

PS: Note that this blog is almost ten years old. There might have been changes in the implementation since that time.

Comment: So, are you saying that this double caching would take place if I use write (or fwrite) on the underlying file of a page that has already been mapped? which since  there is no guarantee of when a page is written to an underlying file, I was always under the impression that doing this would be undefined behaviour anyway, since there would be no way of knowing the order of the writes.

Comment: At what time the data is flushed to the disk is unrelated to the double buffering issue described in the blog (or even triple buffering if you use fwrite and thus the libc cache). In any case, Solaris keeps the page and zfs caches in sync to avoid undefined behavior. If your application is heavily using mmapped files on which it does writes syscalls, you can tune the file system involved to only cache metadata (primarycache=metadata) and then avoid double caching in the first place.

Comment: @jlliagre "You can tune the file system"  -- how?

Comment: @ExcessPhase That was already in my comment: `zfs set primarycache=metadata pool/filesystem`